# Comparing means with drastically different population size

Tags: statistics, average, number-comparison

I am trying to compare averages with different sample size.
I want to find a way to 'normalize' this data. I have read that a weighted average might work, but assigning weights based on what?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The weights are the population numbers:

- Multiply each group's average by its population to give total time per group
- Add total time per group up to give total time overall
- Add up the populations to give total population overall
- Divide total time overall by  total population overall to give average time overall